# Pagination is not working in jQgrid, what I am missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following setup for jQgrid 5.1.0:

```
<div id="grid_container">
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="gridpager"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.fmatter.btnFormatter = function (cellValue, options, rowData, addOrEdit) {
        var btn =
            '<a href="#">' +
            '<img class="api_button" data-id="' + options.rowId + '" src="/images/icons/16x16/view.png" alt="Show API Response data" title="Show API Response data" />' +
            '</a>' +
            '<a href="#">' +
            '<img class="error_button" data-id="' + options.rowId + '" src="/images/icons/16x16/view.png" alt="Show errors" title="Show errors" />' +
            '</a>';
        return btn;
    };

    $(function () {
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            url: '/sf/api-logs',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: {{ colNames|raw }},
            colModel: {{ colFormats|raw }},
            width: 980,
            height: 300,
            pager: "#gridpager",
            toppager: true,
            hoverrows: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autowidth: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            data: [],
            rownumWidth: 50,
            sortable: true,
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                page: 'page',
                total: 'total',
                records: 'records',
                cell: '',
                repeatitems: false
            },
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                if (data.records === 0) {
                    $("#load_grid").addClass("info_msg").html($("<span>", {
                        "class": "grid-empty",
                        "text": "No results were found."
                    })).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
                }
            }
        }).on('click', '.api_button', function () {
            var apiResponseContent = $('#apiResponseContent');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/sf/api-logs/api-response',
                data: {id: $(this).data('id')},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (typeof data[0].error !== 'undefined') {
                        apiResponseContent.text(data[0].error);
                    }

                    apiResponseContent.text(data[0].apiResponse);
                    $('#api_dialog').dialog('open');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        $('#api_dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            height: $(window).height() * 0.9,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        }).show();
    });
</script>
```

But as the image below shown the pagination is not working and the small icon for refresh the grid is not being displayed either, what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have managed to show the `refresh` button by adding the following code:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refresh: true,
    refreshstate: "current"
})
```

But it only appears on the `#gridpagger` what about if I want it also on the top bar?

Here is an example of the data returned by the server: https://gist.github.com/reypm/b1d2a303ba471261e55d72bbef099b74

Comment: You use `datatype: "json"` **without** `loadonce: true` option. Thus you have to implement **server side pagination, sorting** and optionally filtering/sorting. You don't include any example of the output from `url: '/sf/api-logs'` and it's unclear which scenario you want to implement. How many total number of rows could have the grid (100, 1000, 10000, ....)?

Comment: **How many total number of rows could have the grid (100, 1000, 10000, ....)?** Do you implemented paging in your server code? Do you want to load only one page of data in the grid or all data at once? In any way `"total": 0` is wrong, even in case of server side paging scenario.

Comment: @Oleg I haven't implemented server side pagination but I am about to do it. I want to load page by page not all at once since that can kill performance somehow. What should be the value of total? The total count of rows?

Comment: jqGrid allow many options and at least two scenario (two interfaces) in communication with the server: 1) one loads **one specific page** and the server have to informs how many total pages exist. On click on the next/previous page *new request* with the corresponding parameters will be send to the server 2) one can loads **all the data at once**. Paging/sorting and filtering will be done **without** any communication with the server. If you have less then 1000 or less the 10000 rows then it's recommended to use the second scenario, but specify small enough page size (`rowNum`).

Comment: You server response contains 87 rows. It's the typical number of rows or it could be 1 million rows in production?

Comment: @Oleg that's a test DB could be 1 million or even more, is no so harmful since the data is coming from noSQL. Can you give me some advice regarding the `refresh` button at the top? (the UPDATE on my OP)

Comment: I don't full understand what you try to implement. You current server code either returns wrong number of pages or it have not implemented paging at all. **Do you implemented server side paring or not?** **I don't understand your question with "refresh" button, because I don't know what you try to implement**. Moreover, I wrote you that you use "Guriddo jqGrid" and I develop "free jqGrid". Both have only common *old features*. I can gives you advice about the usage old jqGrid 4.7 (the state of the end of 2014) or to explain how you can improve your code for free jqGrid.

Comment: I reread your code once more and I guess that you want to place all navigator button on both top and the bottom pager. You can try to use old option `cloneToTop: true` of `navGrid` (near to `refreshstate: "current"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reported about two problems: pagination not working and the Refresh button appears on the bottom pager only (not on the top-pager).

The problem with Refresh button seems be mostly simple. You use **commercial** Guriddo, which probably still have the same logic of working with pagers like jqGrid 4.7. Old jqGrid has two pager options: `pager` and `toppager`, which values have to be specified in different ways. Working with `toppager` is easy: one can add `toppager: true` option and jqGrid will generate the top-pager div itself and to replace the value of `toppager` from `true` to the id selector of new pager. It will be `toppager: "#grid_toppager"`. On the other side, to create the pager on the bottom of the grid one have to create *somewhere on the HTML page* dummy div, like `<div id="gridpager"></div>` and to use `pager` parameter in the form `pager: "gridpager"`. jqGrid will *move* the div on another place inside of the grid and to fill it with data. Other methods like `navGrid`, `inlineNav`, `navButtonAdd` have to use `#gridpager` or `"#grid_toppager"` as parameter to create the navigator bar and to add buttons to the bar. Thus you have to use the code like

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#grid_toppager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refreshstate: "current"
});
```

or

```
var $grid = $('#grid'),
    topPagerSelector = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'toppager');
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', topPagerSelector, {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refreshstate: "current"
});
```

to create the navigator bar on the top-pager and to add the Refresh button to it. Alternatively you can use `cloneToTop: true` option of `navGrid` to add the same pagers to both pagers:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {
    cloneToTop: true,
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refreshstate: "current"
});
```

You can't use the option if you want to have only one top pager. You will have to use `'#grid_toppager'` with `navButtonAdd` method.

I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid. I simplified the behavior already in the first version of free jqGrid published in the 2015: see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/SMALL-improvements-in-the-usage-of-jqGrid#one-dont-need-to-create-div-idpagerdiv). One can use `pager: true` in the same way like `toppager: true` and one can **skip** pager parameter in `navGrid`, `inlineNav`, `navButtonAdd`. The usage of `navGrid` could be

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refreshstate: "current"
});
```

to add the navigator buttons on all pagers of the grid (top, bottom or both).

It's only one small difference between free jqGrid and Guriddo jqGrid. There are hundreds of other changes. I recommend you to consider to migrate to free jqGrid even if you [payed](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) Guriddo jqGrid license. I'd recommend you to read [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) with the base information about the usage of free jqGrid.

The paging of data don't work because the response from your server is wrong. It looks like

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total": 0,
  "records": 67,
  "rows": [
    { "id": "590a363477336501ad44ab02", "dataObject": "Account", ...},
    ...
    { "id": "590c97197ad70f00575a310a", "dataObject": "AgreementHistory", ...}
  ]
}
```

You use `datatype: "json"` option **without** `loadonce: true` option, which corresponds **server side paging**. It means that jqGrid send to `url` requests with `rows` and `page` parameter. The first request, which send jqGrid will contains `page=1&rows=20` (20 is the default value of `rowNum` parameter of jqGrid) and the server *have to* return 20 or less rows (return only one requested page of data). Additional `total` and `records` property informs jqGrid about the total number or pages and records. Based on the value of `total` parameter jqGrid will **disable** pager buttons and the user will be not able to make paging correctly.

One the other side, your server response contains **wrong value of `total` property** and all 67 rows instead of 20 requested rows. Other 47 rows of the serve response will be just ignored by jqGrid.

If you have scenario, where the total number of records is not large (like 67 in you case), then it's recommended to add `loadonce: true` option (and `forceClientSorting: true` additionally in case of usage free jqGrid) and to modify the server response to

```
[
  { "id": "590a363477336501ad44ab02", "dataObject": "Account", ...},
  ...
  { "id": "590c97197ad70f00575a310a", "dataObject": "AgreementHistory", ...}
]
```

with **all rows** of the grid. jqGrid will fill internal `data` parameter, it will change `datatype` to `"local"` automatically after the first loading the data. As the result paging, sorting and filtering/searching (try `filterToolbar` or `search: true` of `navGrid`) *locally* without any additional communication to the server. It essentially simplify the server code and improves the performance of jqGrid. Even relatively large number of rows can be processed very quickly if you use small enough page size (like `rowNum: 20` or `rowNum: 10`). You can try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-15-60000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) with 60000 rows, 15 columns and 25 rows per page. You can test the time of paging, sorting and filtering.

Comment: Wow, this answer is amazing! Thank you so much, as per use the free version it doesn't depends on my decision otherwise I would be using the free one which has better support. AFAIK we didn't paid for the non-free version since it's jQuery and so far still "free"

Comment: @ReynierPM: You are welcome! jQuery and jqGrid are different products. In you open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` you will see the text "License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334" in the comment directly at the beginning. You need opening the URL you will see the prices and the license agreement. On the other side "free jqGrid" can be used under MIT or GPLv2 licenses completely free of charge.