# Jq grid paging not working while binding on ajax response

Tags: jquery, grid

I am binding grid on response of ajax call but passing parameter to grid paging is not working.
what am I missing? Do i need to enable any flag for grid or i need to change way of implementations?

```
getDatCallBack(res) {
    var data1 = JSON.parse(res.rows);

   var GRIDDATA= {
       total: 2 ,page: 1, records: 10, rows: data1
    }

    $("#tblrent").jqGrid({
        datastr: GRIDDATA,
        datatype: "jsonString",
        height: "auto",
        colNames: stock.getColumnName(data1[0]),
        colModel: stock.getColmodel(data1[0]),
        caption: "Stocks",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        pager: $("#divPager"),
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "rows", page: "page", total: "total", records: "records" },
        loadComplete: function () {
            // stock.getData(stock.addJqriddata);
        },
        onSelectRow: function (id) {

        },
        onCellSelect: function (rowId, iCol, content, event) {
            var rowData = jQuery('#tblrent').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
            var rowData1 = JSON.stringify(rowData);
            localStorage.setItem('selectedRow', rowData1);
        }
    });
    },
```

Comment: use `loadonce: true` option. reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812777/pagination-is-not-working-in-jqgrid-what-i-am-missing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with passing parameter to pagging (jqGrid pass automatically this parameter), but you have a typo in datatype value

The definition

```
datatype : "jsonString"
```

is wrong. Instead use

```
datatype: "jsonstring"
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

When using datatype:"jasonstrig" after the first load grid automatically go to local datatype and there is no need to use loadonce:true, since it is set automatically